# Heroku Database Workflow and safety net

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm currently deploying a rails app to **heroku** via **codeship** from the *master* branch. My app development is getting to a point where I want other users to be using the database and storing data.
I'm trying to determine **what is the best way to manage the database when reset is no longer an option?** Because the database will be full of user data.
I've done some research but I was *hoping for a second opinion* on these options. Is this a solid approach or is there an easier way to do this?

For General Fixes and local testing
To **pull** the database to my local machine:

```
heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA mylocaldb --app sushi
```

**PUSH** local to internet:

```
heroku pg:push mylocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA --app sushi
```

**SAVE BACKUP** I would use:

```
heroku pg:backups:capture --app sushi
```

**SCHEDULE BACKUP** I would use:

```
 heroku pg:backups:schedule DATABASE_URL --at '02:00 America/Los_Angeles' --app sushi
```

In the worst case scenario I could **RESTORE** a backup with:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore b101 DATABASE_URL --app sushi
```

**UPDATE**
The pull code above didn't work so I found this. I had to pull specifically development to get it to run locally in my dev environment. It works but is it the correct way to go about it?

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL dbname_development --app appname
```